# SortBy crash violates contract

Tags: java, android

Hey guys I have this code to compare by duration but I keep getting this error:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException Comparison method
>   violates its general contract!

Here is my code:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<MyProduct>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(MyProduct lhs, MyProduct rhs) {
        Integer lDuration = (lhs != null ? lhs.getDuration() :0);
        Integer rDuration = (rhs != null ? rhs.getDuration() :0);

        return lDuration.compareTo(rDuration);
    }
});
```

Comment: What are the durations being compared that lead to the error?

Answer (score 0):

You are violating the requirements of [consistency with equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

> When we say that the ordering imposed by c on S is consistent with equals, we mean that the quotient for the ordering is the equivalence relation defined by the objects' equals(Object) method(s):
>
> ```
> {(x, y) such that x.equals(y)}
> ```

You are saying that null is equal to an instance with zero duration, which it is not, because `zeroDuration.equals(null)` is false (or, at least, [it should be](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-)), and `null.equals(zeroDuration)` results in an exception.

You should decide either to put all null elements first, or all null elements last.

Comment: could you plz give me a lil example on how you would do it i tho i undestood it but i havent yet solved the problem